# How to show the continuity

Tags: analysis, algebraic-topology, continuity, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

Below picture is from the Jost's Riemannian Geometry. At last ,I don't know how get the homotopy. It is not proved that $c_s(t)$ is continue for any $s$. So I can't get the $\Gamma(t,s)$ is continue.How to prove it ?

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: You use opposite notation from the book. Is your question: "Why is $c_t$ a continuous function of $s$ for any $t \in S^1$"?

Comment: @AlexProvost   I want to show  for given $s_0$,  $c_t(s_0)$ is a continuous function of $t$.

Comment: @AlexProvost   continuous of $s$ is proved by 1.4.4 .But seemly ,it is not enough to show that $\Gamma(t,s)$ is continuous of $t$ and $s$